# Can I place a text box in Fancybox 2?

Tags: jquery, textbox, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to place a textbox into Fancybox2.

However, when I click the textbox then Fancybox code seems to reload. How can I prevent this from happening?

You can see an example of the problem here; http://jsfiddle.net/geefg/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/64epM/

I did a trick by replacing the content with the content by doing:

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0,
        afterLoad : function() {
            this.content = this.content.html();                            
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Just as I was beginning to pull my hair out!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you click on the content of the fancybox, is like clicking on `<a>`, that's reload the page.

Try to put `input` field in hidden `div` :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#data">Some content</a>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="data"><input type="text" id="TextBox3" name="TextBox3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done another trick 
which makes it works perfectly

before calling .fancybox

just check if the div that will be shown by fancybox is visible or not

like this

```
 if ($(".fancybox").is(":visible")) {
     return false;
 }
else{
   $(".fancybox").fancybox({
     padding : 0
    });
}
```

this will your text editable